# Highlight clicked day in responsive calendar

Tags: calendar, responsive

I am working on a responsive calendar and when I click on a particular day, I need to add a class to that day (so the selected day can be highlighted).

Below is my code:

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
    weekends: false,
    onDayClick: function(events) {
        key = $(this).data('year')+'-'+ $(this).data('month')+'-'+$(this).data('day');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the correct day element and then set a class on the parent. Could go something like this:

```
onDayClick: function(events) {
  // unselect others
  $('.active').removeClass('active');

  var year = $(this).data('year')
  var month = $(this).data('month')
  var day = $(this).data('day');

  var dayLink = $('[data-day=' + day + '][data-month=' + month + '][data-year=' + year + ']')
  dayLink.parent().addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thanks madsgodvinjensen, It works. Also when i click on another day, I will have to remove the "active" class from previous one

Comment: How can I remove the previously selected day on the click of another day?

Comment: I just updated my reply to include removing the active class from other selected days.

Comment: @madsgodvinjensen I see your excelent response. It help me too much. Please, I need also know the month and year when the user click on next /prev link or  into event onMonhChange. the values data['year] and data['month'] don´t work there. Could you give me a tip about it?